# MVVM - What's the correct track regarding Nested Lists and View Models?

Tags: wpf, list, mvvm, nested, viewmodel

Here's the thing:

I have a GetHistoryLog View, its view-model, and its model.

I have a listbox which points to a `ObservableCollection<ChangesetEntity>`

I have another view specialized on getting versioned items, so it's a VersionedItemView, its view-model, and its model.

Now I want GetHistoryLog View to access specific versioned items within its changesets. Each changeset can have multiple versioned items. What is the best way to "connect" the two view-models?

Here's what I want to do, a Tree-view containing all the changesets and child files, and a single list view containing all the changesets, with an option to click the changeset and view the modified files.

Basically, access a list of items inside a list of items, and at the same time have the option to access a specific index inside this list.

Do I need to create another view-model? What is the best solution without creating havoc in the code?

I hope I was clear enough

Thanks in adv.!

EDIT: Also, is there a way to set the DataContext of a control to some specific item in a list, dynamically?

**EDIT: Trying to explain more clearly:**

`HistoryLogEntryModel -> GetHistoryLogVM -> GetHistoryLogUserControl`

`VersionedItemLogModel -> GetVersionedItemsLogVM -> GetVersionedItemsLogUserControl`

What I want is:

`HistoryLogEntryModel + VersionedItemLogModel -> ? -> GetCompleteHistoryLogWithVersionedItemsUserControl` 
(shorter name, but just for understanding)

Comment: Can you provide a more succinct description of your domain? imho, it makes it easier to work on M-V-VM problems if your model is well understood.

Comment: The additional description of the model you provided isn't exactly what I was looking for.  It seems like you have a HistoryLogEntry object. It contains a ChangeSet object (collection of?). The ChangeSet contains _n_ VersionedItemLog objects (another collection). Does this describe your domain model without the clutter of VMs and Views/UserControls.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. Yes, this describes my domain model: HistoryLogEntry contains a collection of ChangeSet objects. Each changeset contains n versioned items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I don't think you need anything more.  You already have a very hierarchical object graph of your domain which will support the parent child relationships you're describing already.

I think you just need to polish up on your approach to binding and object presentation. Here is a [good post from MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx) that can help you with that and it also has advice for dealing with with [Hierarchical Data Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx#id0190094) for use with a WPF TreeView.

If you want to do a binding that dynamically changes the DataContext of a control based on the SelectedItem of another control (ListBox for example), you can use the following binding syntax:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=sourceElementNameHere, Path=SelectedItem, 
    Mode=OneWay}"
```

Here is another link to a [good MSDN article on binding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx).